# python rsa private-encrypt to comunicate with node.js

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, cryptography, rsa

First things first,
SECURITY DISCLAIMER:

I'm fully aware that if I use private-encryption -> public-decryption the "encrypted" message is is readable for anyone who has access to the so called "public key".
In a normal use case of rsa this would be fatal!
But in my case the "public key" is meant to be private too.
I'm trying to establish an encrypted connection where the full control stays on one party. 
One of the partners is untrusted and if he would got compromised I want to be sure no one else can use the interface (to prevent privilege escalation).
As you can see in this use case encryption itself is in fact not the main reason of asymmetric "encrytion". 
You actually get an encrypted data stream which can't be manipulated from a third party even if the key is leaked.
My actual communication should run between a node.js and a python environment.
The [URSA](https://github.com/quartzjer/ursa) node lib already has a feature for the private encryption.
Sadly [pyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/) doesn't support that for reasons mentioned above earlier.
I already tried to cheese the lib and used the private exponent to instantiate a public key object but nodejs can't decrypt the result(not a big surprise).
Does anyone know how to tackle this problem?
Is there another way to get python to do actual private key encryption?
Maybe there is another python lib capable of doing so i couldn't find?
Or maybe its possible to get the nodejs lib to decrypt my cheesie private key encryption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a working solution for me.
I simply hacked an extra method in the signing object of pyCrypto which does exactly what i want.
This works with python 2.7.9 and 3.4 as far as I tested it.
In the file `"[...]/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_v1_5.py"` is the class `"PKCS115_SigScheme"`
I simply added following method:

```
def private_encrypt(self, msg):
    modBits = Crypto.Util.number.size(self._key.n)
    k = ceil_div(modBits,8) # Convert from bits to bytes
    PS = bchr(0xFF) * (k - len(msg) - 3)
    m = self._key.decrypt(b("\x00\x01") + PS + bchr(0x00) + msg)
    S = bchr(0x00)*(k-len(m)) + m
    return S
```

It's just a manipulated copy of the "sign" function.

Usage looks like:

```
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
plain_message="Hi, I'm going to be encrypted with a private key."
key = RSA.generate(4096)
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
bin_enc_msg = signer.private_encrypt(plain_message.encode())
```

The decryption after the base64 encoded transfer in nodejs with [URSA](https://github.com/quartzjer/ursa) publicDecrypt works fine.
It should be clear from the imports but I want to mention this nonetheless: 
This actually encrypts with PKCS1.5 padded rsa.

Another solution would be to combine symmetric encryption with asymmetric signing to be able to verify it but that would require additional effort and complexity I don't want or need.

Comment: How did you figure the implementation of `private_encrypt`?

Comment: I looked up how signing is supposed to work. I'm basically just signing the data but instead of a hash I use my actual data. And for some details I looked at how the ursa node.js lib decrypt data and what it expects.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to connect a python environment and Node.js with encryption and don't require the use of third party verification, are you required to use RSA Public key encryption? It really sounds like what you're trying to accomplish is [Symmetric-key Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) and you could use [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). The pyCrypto Library already supports this, and some googling provided [this](https://github.com/chengxianga2008/node-cryptojs-aes) library for Node.js on git hub.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is exactly what i don't want. If someone gets the password of an symmetric encryption he can decrypt and manipulate and reencrypt the communication. That is what I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: You might look at [pyOpenSSL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL) which has the tools for doing PKI / private public key encryption. I would say if you set up your environment with each server doing a PKI like setup for 2 way communication, and don't use third party certs, you're open to MITM attacks, and cert management is a pain.

Comment: I have the feeling no one understands what I am trying to describe. probably my fault. The public key exchange is happening securely over an protected channel and is saved permanently to a file at the client. After that I'm using this technique exactly because its not vulnerable to MITM. And btw pyopenssl doesn't support privatekey encryption at all.

Comment: to clarify my last statement, the normal rsa encryption works by encrypting with the public key. but I want the other way around and I know its possible and its use to do message signing but the typical libraries prevent you from using this function by yourself. Even if it would be useful.

Comment: I haven't used it, but [this](http://stuvel.eu/rsa) may be what your looking for. Are you hoping that you can have a private key in one environment, and the "public" key in the other and have the private key encrypt comms than public key decrypt for one direction, or alternatively have the "public" key encrypt and have the private key decrypt?

Comment: I want both, but only private encrypt isn't possible with most of the libraries and that's why I ask this question here. But again, python-RSA doesn't support private encryption either.